# Please can someone show how the differential of a product in ln can be rewritten?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to use the following property of the differential of ln that it can be written in this form to continue with a proof but I am struggling to derive this result-please can someone explain how this is derived?

$$d(\ln(xy))=d(\ln(y))\left[1+y \frac{d\ln(x)}{dy}\right]$$

Comment: Can you please rewrite your equation?

Comment: i do not know how to write it in code! i am sorry

Comment: Click on Help at the top. Choose the Help Center. Click on the sentence"How Do I Format Mathematics Here?" which  is somewhere in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0):

not at all a vigorous derivation but I think this will suffice for now. sorry for lack of formatting!

[image]